# Why can't I test on my phone(P40) with the apk file I've sent on Cloud Testing?

Tags: testing, huawei-mobile-services

Why can't I test on my phone(P40) with the apk file I've sent on Cloud Testing?

Please give instructions on how to install the program on your mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Testing allows compatibility tests of your app on diverse real devices. The test automatically detects compatibility issues, including exceptions during app installation/reinstallation/uninstallation/launches, crashes, ANR problems, unexpected exit, running errors, UI errors, black/white screen issues, and exit failures. Please refer to Huawei's official guide in details:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-cloudtest-compatibilitytest-0000001082683302

1. Sign in to [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) and click My projects.
2. Click your project from the project list.
3. Go to **Project settings > Quality > Cloud Testing**.
4. Click Test for free. For the first test, an introduction to Cloud Testing is displayed on the right of the page. Skip steps 6 and 7 for the first test and skip steps 4 and 5 if you have created a test.
5. Find the Compatibility test card and click Start now on the card.
6. Go to **Quality > Cloud Testing**. On the displayed test list page, click New test in the upper right corner
7. Click the Compatibility test tab
8. Click Upload (max 2 GB) in the Apps area to upload your APK. After the upload is complete, select the app to be tested and click Next.
9. Filter and select test devices as required. By default, all available test devices are displayed
10. Click OK. In the displayed Information dialog box, you can create another test or click View test list to go to the test result page.

**Please note:** A test may take about 60 minutes. You can also view the test result from the Cloud Testing service page. For details, please refer to steps 11 to 14.

But if you are asking about testing your APK on real device , then please use debug feature of tools like Android studio  etc. To start debugging an APK, click Profile or debug APK from the Android Studio Welcome screen. Or, if you already have a project open, click **File > Profile or Debug APK** from the menu bar. In the next dialog window, select the APK you want to import into Android Studio and click OK.

For details , please refer to  :

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger

If you are facing issue in installing APK manually on P40 then try allowing File Manager/other apps to install unknown apps by going to **Settings > Apps > Menu > Special access > Install unknown apps**. Or if still unable to install APK ,please go to the device department website for help get more professional services. The link is:
https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/